# Should I use "is" or "are" in this sentence?

Tags: word-choice

It goes on until everything Job has ever known, including his children *is* gone.

It goes on until everything Job has ever known, including his children *are* gone.

Comment: You should start by including the comma you left out, then it will all immediately click into place. Right now *neither* sentence makes any sense as written.

Comment: I'm guessing you mean after children? This still does not settle my question...

Comment: @RobJohnson - Maybe not, but it's the first step toward discovering the answer. Keep parsing until everything is making sense.

Comment: “It goes on until everything Job has ever known (including his children) _XX_ gone”. Clearly, once you realise that “including his children” is parenthetical and can be removed from the sentence without changing it (structurally), it should be obvious that it should be “everything Job has ever known […] _is_ gone”.

Comment: "Clearly" I feel degraded, thanks for the help.

Comment: No degrading going on here. No one has called you stupid for asking, but we did drop hints to see if the light might come on before the answer was given, in the spirit of "Teach a man to fish..." I even included the phrase *everything is* in my comment as a subtle hint. If you reread the comments with the idea that we are all hoping that you figure it out in a way that will help you in the future, you'll see there was assistance, but not degrading. Janus' used of the word "clearly" is used like "therefore" - a way to see the jump from A to B.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet It becomes clearest when you realize that just plain *Everything [...] is gone* is all it takes. The rest is just distraction.

Comment: The thing is, the more parenthetical plural terms come between the true subject and verb, the more people are inclined to make the verb agree with the parenthetical items. So although by strict grammatical principles there's only one defensible answer to OP's question, in practice even competent speakers are quite capable of using the "wrong" verb form in certain contexts.

Answer (score 1):

**"Is"**

**"Everything"** is singular, so you would not use the plural **"are"** in this sentence.  The easiest way to tell is to simplify the sentence.

"It goes on until **everything** Job has ever known, including his children **is gone**."

Everything is gone.

Comment: You still don't seem to have the needed comma.

Comment: "Everything" takes singular agreement - it certainly doesn't demand or even suggest a unipartite referent.